# Dynamic height of UITableview Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have set

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 88.0
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Also I have done numberOfLines of `UILabel` to zero.
I haven't given any fixed height/width constraint in IB.
Still my UITableviewCell height is not expanded accordingly.

Please suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check whether you are explicitly defining tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath method.
If so remove that method or if you want to use it because of several cells existing there , you can return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for that particular cell height.

Answer (score 8):

Try This:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

EDIT

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Define above Both Methods.It Solve The Problem.

Comment: I have extra cells as well with different heights.

Answer (score 1):

You should check that the first view from top, has a constraint to the top of the cell, and the bottom one, to the bottom of the cell. That way, the cell will know how big is its content.
And check your log for constraints conflicts.
You can use this for reference:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift